# Mesh Cylindrical Symmetrize

Tags: edit-mode

How can I simply copy/reflect the highlighted geometry across the X-axis of this cylindrically symmetrical object?

[image]

I was hoping Mesh/Symmetrize would have the answer, but it currently can create only planar mirror symmetry. I guess what I need is a tool that creates mesh symmetry across an axis (radial, diagonal, cylindrical symmetry). My search of Blender documents found virtually nothing about mesh diagonal symmetry; almost all references to 'symmetry' seemed to imply/assume just planar mirror symmetry. Some discussions of Radial symmetry were about multi-object symmetry not intra-mesh symmetry.

Note that the somewhat messy example mesh is what remains after a few hours of cleaning up apparently random 'Non-Flat' faces in preparation for 3D printing.

Comment: Maybe you should redo your object from scratch with good practice from the beginning? Do you have an image of your reference object?

Comment: Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/UIUWH7N) what you mean?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks. My 'messy' comment was meant to be parenthetical. I would have done what you suggest if it were the faster route, but all of the model vertices are there because of their absolute coordinates in an engineering sense, following several trial adjustments. I'll address cleaning up such a model later as a separate question.

Comment: @Robin Betts Yes. Thank-you, What tool/setting were you using? Even more, I was hoping for a tool that would apply axial symmetry  after the fact, like Symmetrize.

Comment: @cappa .. that's a 2 element rotational array, 180 degrees..